# How to load a file using javascript without revealing the source?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

I am currently working on a project which allows a user to upload a 3D model in .STL file format and then displays the 3D view for an audience.

There are many javascript libraries that allow you to do this however they do not hide the sourcefile.

How do I make sure people are able to use the 3D view without being able to download the model from URL.

With kind regards.

Comment: If it runs on the client's browser, they already have it.

Comment: You aren't very clear about your execution environment, but if a browser can run a Javascript file, then anyone can see the Javascript source.  You cannot prevent viewing of the source.

Comment: Another relevant dup reference: [Is there a way to hide javascript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862880/is-there-a-way-to-hide-javascript-code/7862891#7862891) and [How can I “cloak” my Javascript and CSS files using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691941/how-can-i-cloak-my-javascript-and-css-files-using-php/8691957#8691957).

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. I will have to find another way then