# How can you hide your js files so they can not be viewed by tools such as firebug

Tags: javascript

I have a node web app where i want to hide js files which I have created for the client side?

how can this be achieved? I do not want people viewing the files.

Comment: if its on web, it can be taken

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i hide javascript code in a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage)

Answer (score 2):

Node runs on the server. All the JavaScript that runs on the server can be hidden. Any JavaScript delivered to the client and run in the user's browser cannot be hidden (though it can be obfuscated).

Comment: Thanks will have a look into obfuscating them

Comment: Keep in mind that obfuscation still only takes you so far – anyone with serious interest can just deobfuscate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "hide" the JS files since the JS interpreter also has to be able to access them.

You can however *obfuscate* them, so that they cannot be easily read.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible but you can use something like [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to make the javascript unintelligible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the js files but you can provide security to the JS files by minifying them.

You can find many minifier in the online.

[JS Compressor](http://jscompress.com/) is a one of the minifiers.

Try it.