# How to hide source code of a function like angular website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you open the developer tools in the AngularJS website, some functions stay with the source code hidden.
Is there a way to do it?

Example:
[image: angular-site]

The function toString is returning a classic "native code" of javascript native/pre-compiled functions instead returning the real source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide javascript code in a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is a reference of Array.isArray;

```
/**
 * @name angular.isArray
 * @module ng
 *
 * @description
 * Determines if a reference is an `Array`.
 *
 * @param {*} value Reference to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if `value` is an `Array`.
 */
var isArray = Array.isArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't* do this.  [`isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) is part of the [JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2) and hence implemented by the environment in which you're running, and so is native code.  Any JavaScript you yourself serve up can be inspected on the client.

---

*You *could* write your own user agent / JavaScript engine...