# How to hide JScripts in Developers tools?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to hide the scripts that you use from the `Developers Tool` ? I see in some of the browser game that I play that the scripts are not there.

Cheers. Thanks.

[image: Here is the Picture]

Comment: No, it is not possible. If you can't find scripts from dev tools, there are no scripts in that game ...

Comment: @Teemu I only found 1 script from that game. I don't know why. That's why I ask it here.

Comment: Thanks all maybe i will try to use what [Addinall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage) answer.