# How to print a jquery get in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get('https://{URL}', function(data, status){
        list = JSON.parse(data);
        parseDocument(list)
        fct()
    })
});
</script>

<html>
<body>
<div class="headers">
<p> <b> Input Values: </b> </p>
<p> <b> Results </b> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to print the data from get() next to Input Values:
How do I do that?

Comment: In your HTML, add a span with an ID: `<span id="mySpan"></span>`, and in your JS, do `$('#mySpan').text(/* Your content */);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous">    
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="headers">
            <p> <b> Input Values: </b> </p>
            <p id="results"> <b> Results </b> </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = ["value1", "value2"];
    $("#results").append(data.join(", "));
});
</script>
```

Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/eduard-malakhov/pen/wgXqQV

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It gave me an idea, but I need to use something like this for JS

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $.get("URL")
    $("#results").append(data.join(", "));
    });

as i do not know the input values, i need to retrieve them from an URL. But the example i gave here does not populate the #results.

Comment: @AdrianFelea but the rest you have already in your code. Your `list` is the data you want to fill in, isn't it?

Comment: yes that is i need to print in the html page next to "Input Values:" line.

Comment: thank you for all your replies, i figured it out. Now i just can't believe i didn't see it!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In your head and not above your html. 
It's safer to place it in an external document: [How do I hide javascript code in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage)
and then `<script type="text/javascript">document.write(list);</script>`

Hope this helps.