# Hide Bundles content from external viewing in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have registered bundles in Global.asax.cs file. When I enter my domain name with bundles path in browser, I am able to view minified js,css content in browser. 
How to hide contents from external viewing which are added in bundles. Below URL should not display any content in the browser.  Any suggestion please.

https://examplewebsite.com/website/bundles/jscode

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jscode").Include(
           "~/Scripts/UIScripts/Module1/MainCode1.js",
           "~/Scripts/UIScripts/Module2/MainCode2.js",
           "~/Scripts/UIScripts/Module3/MainCode3.js"
           ));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _restrict contents_?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - When I hit given URL in the browser it should not display js(javascript) contents in the browser.

Comment: What does it matter? (they are visible in any web page the user navigates to that includes that bundle)

Comment: That's impossible. How do you expect the browser to the run the js if it can't access it.

Comment: If your putting security in your js then this is a bad idea FYI.

Comment: If you think that you need to restrict users, to view js content in browser, then change your code/project, this is wrong solution.

Comment: I just want to restrict external viewing only.

Comment: @Ask_SO you can't tell browser to get your js files privately and show users only its working part.

Comment: Why? It makes no sense to do this it add's no benefit whatsoever and more to the point, you can't do it. *you can't tell browser to get your js files privately* no

Comment: I have added one more URL. If I am able to view the code directly then it is security concern right?

Comment: @Ask_SO. What security concern?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke-- In case , If we use session variable in js file it is vulnerable to attack right?

Comment: Why would you be using a `Session` variable? And how would you do that anyway considering its an external js file (razor code is not parsed in external files)

Comment: @Ask_SO You want browser should read the content but external users should not view the content. Is this your expectation?

Comment: @G01 - Exactly. When I hit direct url, browser should not display contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide javascript code in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundles are nothing more than JavaScript files.

They need to be public and accessible so that the browser can download and execute them. As such you cannot protect them from being viewed. You can minify them, but you can't stop them from being seen.

Answer (score 1):

> for enable bundle  `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` and
>   disable bundle  `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`

With enable bundle of the files available, but with a lot of complexity

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Filter").Include(
               "~/Scripts/UIScripts/Module1/MainFilter1.js",
               "~/Scripts/UIScripts/Module2/MainFilter2.js",
               "~/Scripts/UIScripts/Module3/MainFilter3.js"
               ));
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the question, and certainly does not prevent the user navigating to the bundle.