# How to remove my website's source code from browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webbrowser-control, datasource, feathersjs

I have created my website but it shows all of its source code into browser's source code static files section. It is not secured and i want to remove all of the data. My application is created in react.js and feathers.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide javascript code in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript)

Comment: When you say source code do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: We'd really have to know a lot more about what you're doing and what exact problem you are observing.  Javascript that runs in the browser will ALWAYS be visible to anyone.  That is a function of the browser architecture.  Code that needs to be private must be on the server and the client makes requests of the server to run that  code.  A properly configured server will not expose any of its code to any browser.  There is no way to prevent client-side code that runs in the browser from being seen.

Comment: Use name mangling when you're minifying your js files. And don't serve the `.map` files in production. The code will still be visible to everyone but it will be very hard to know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to hide/remove source code from browser.

But I like to add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` with build command in package.json file. it will not generate .map files which have source code.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Remember there is no  (&&) operator between `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`  and `react-scripts build`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if your build is properly minified or not. 
Creating a production build would bundle and minify the files which helps to protect the source code.

Refer this thread - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4162