# Encrypt javascript file

Tags: javascript, encryption

I don't find any info about that,so asking here.
Is somebody ever used some tool to protect javascript files? And totaly encrypt them?
Because I found this tool that seems like can totaly encrypt JS?
What do you think?
http://webtools.securitygeeks.net/p/blog-page_26.html?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020368/how-to-hide-or-encrypt-javascript-code

Comment: No, just run the JS in a separate file, view source, and bam! It's unencrypted!

Comment: Yes, that code will encrypt your source code. Then whoever downloads it just has to decrypt it, which is basically trivial.

Comment: What is that for? I have tested and the encryption double sized my code. Are you thinking in store confidential data on it?

Comment: If this is for validation reasons, all validation should run through the server-side anyways, security through obscurity isn't the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

That tool is useless. It declares a global variable called `teksasli` which contains your original script in a plain string. just look at the value of that variable in any console to see the original source.

There is no point in trying to encrypt Javascript, because the user/browser needs to decrypt it in order to run it.

Comment: It uses both XOR and base64 - must be secure ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obfuscate the source code, You could try GWT http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/ (The Google Web Toolkit ).